# Two types of for loop - how come only one of them is working?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following code in Javascript:

```
var controller = {
initApp: function(){
    var getCartData = $.ajax({ url: '/cart' }),
        getCategoryData = $.ajax({ url: '/categories' }),
        getSupplierData = $.ajax({ url: '/suppliers'}),
        getProdcuts = $.ajax({url: '/products'});

    // Main controller logic starts when all data are loaded in
    $.when(getCartData, getCategoryData, getSupplierData, getProdcuts
    ).done( function( cart, categories, suppliers, products ) {
        var model = new Model(cart, categories, suppliers, JSON.parse(products[0]));

        console.log(model.products);
        console.log(typeof model.products);

        for(var i = 0; i<model.products.length; i++){
            console.log(model.products[i]);
        }

        for(product in model.products){
            console.log(product);
        }

    });
}
```

};

I would like to iterate through model.products. At the end of the code I use two types of for loops. How come only one of them (the first one) is working as expected?
The second one prints numbers in the length of the array.

Comment: probably you want to use `for ... of` instead of `for ... in`

Comment: Read [for...in | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) You are iterating over the properties not the values. Then read [for...of | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0):

Produkt is a key too:

```
a={a:1,b:2}
for(key in a){
 alert(key);// a.   B.  
}
```

So you need to do:

```
for(product in model.products){ 
 console.log(model[product]);
 }
```

But you should use the normal for loop. Why? Because the prototype is also handled in keys:

```
Array.prototype.test=2;
```

Run booth loops with this code executed before. For in will also echo 2, what you dont want...